# Check (Cheque) Remittance Printing on separate sheet - AX 2009

Tags: axapta

We're using AX 2009. When one user prints cash disbursement checks, the remittance is printed on the same physical sheet as the check. This is the way we'd like it to work for all our users. However, when one user prints, the remittance is printed on a separate page.

Any hints/suggestions/detailed instructions on where to look in AX to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and the solution for us was to enable edge to edge printing on printer setup when generating payments. Might not be your problem, but worth a try, took us 2 days to figure it out!!

Answer (score -1):

Check the users default printer is a real valid printer.

Check the printer setup of the check report, especially check the paper size. To do this press  the "Options" button in the report dialog form.

If all fails, delete the Windows printer, recreate, set as default, then retry.

Comment: "Check the printer setup of the check report, especially check the paper size." Any idea where in AX that is? That is my problem. I am new to AX and don't know where settings are.

Comment: Added "Options" button to answer

Comment: @Brent, did you find the "Options" button?

Comment: Nope, I'm not sure exactly where it is. You mean the check report in the AOT? Can you give me a > delimited list of what to click on to get to the options button?

Comment: No, run the report from the menu, form or whatever, then look for the "Options" button. Options are saved per user per report. You will need to run using the users credentials.